# Displaying images in bootstrap's popover via knockout binding *almost* working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a custom knockout binding that allows an image to be bound to a knockout popover:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapPopover = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        var defaultOptions = {trigger: 'hover'};
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaultOptions, options);
        $(element).popover(options);
    }
};
```

My goal is to allow users to hover over a thumbnail (with max dimensions defined) to see a full-sized image, perhaps as big as the screen allows (I think bootstrap's popover already takes care of responsive-ness).

How can I get the full sized image appearing in the popover?

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/117/

html:

```
 <a class="image-content-saved" href="#" data-bind="bootstrapPopover: { content: sideOneTextContent(), html:true }">
                <img src="http://www.dailydesigninspiration.com/diverse/adv/publicis/Omax-Wide-Angle-Lenses.jpg" />
            </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to knockout or bootstrap but how you have styled your thumbnail:

```
img {
    max-height: 160px;
    height: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

So your selector `img` is too generic and also gets applied to the image in the popover. You can fix it with adding a new rule for images inside the popover.

Bootstrap adds the class `popover` to the popover's container so you can write something like:

```
.popover img {   
   max-height: none;
   max-width: none !important;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vG9ds/)

Comment: Thanks nemesv - that makes sense.  Any idea why the responsiveness isn't working?  I was trying to use percentages so that resizing the screen didn't ever hide any of the image.